# WSO2 API Manager: Creating SOAP or websocket API changes existing APIs types

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm using WSO2's API Manager version 2.5.0 (https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/tree/v2.5.0).

**Problem:**
I create a REST API then create a SOAP API. When I edit the REST API looking at the first page (Design), it shows a SOAP endpoint instead of the REST endpoints. If I then create a websocket API and view the design page of the REST and SOAP APIs, the endpoints aren't shown indicating they are now websocket APIs. If I then create another REST API, viewing the design page of the other APIs shows they are now back to normal.

**Question:**
What is causing this to happen? Is there a fix for it? Does anyone have information about this? I've done extensive research looking through their docs, their github, stackoverflow, and google searches with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in 2.5.0 and fixed in 2.6.0.

**Edit:** My bad. It seems it's fixed after 2.6.0 release.

You can use the development branch[1].

[1] https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/tree/2.x

Comment: I tested 2.6.0 and the problem still exists. I tested the latest release of 2.6.0 (https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/releases/tag/v2.6.0).